# Angularjs - ui-router with dynamic number of parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

we have a requirement like this. we use ui-router

```
#/plan-details/unlimited
#/plan-details/unlimited/country-id/10024
#/plan-details/local/county-id/12322
#/plan-details/national/country-id/10024/state-id/12322
#/plan-details/state/state-id/12322/country-id/10024
```

here the url pattern is:

```
#/plan-details/:planCode/country-id/10024/state-id/12322
```

here some times country-id may present or may not present
and some times state-id may present or may not present.

We looked at using this

```
#/plan-details/:planCode/country-id/:countryId/state-id/:stateId
```

But in our case, countryId is not mandatory and some times URL can be simply

```
#/plan-details/:planCode/state-id/:stateId
```

How to configure this in ui-router?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried creating a route for each case?

Comment: Creating a route for each case works fine. But as we have many number of combinations, it is not a viable solution.